# Entity Framework: Many-To-Many Relations from one class

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-relationship

I have class "Image", which contains byte array and MIME type for a picture.

So, i want to use this "Images" anywhere.

for ex, I create class User, in which i want to store some photos, so i write

```
public virtual ICollection<Image> Pictures {get;set;}
```

I want this data to have many-to-many relation with my "Image" table, but i dont need to have "back link" to every user, that uses this picture

```
public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;} //in "Image" class for ex.
```

and for more, I dont want to rewrite my "Image" class when I would add, for example, "BlogPost" class, which also can have some "Images"(i mean ICollection Pictures).

So, what should I do?
Should i rewrite my "Image" class for back links every time, or mb there is a way to store make mapping only from "one side"?

Comment: I think EF needs an association on both sides for many-to-many relationships. This link may help you: http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/05/17/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-6-many-valued-associations.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well, I decided to put my "Image" class as a complex type. And just create classes for "UserImage", "BlogPostImage" and so on.

Probably, if I cant do smthing using superpopular framework, that means that my arcitecture is wrong....